# How does one get the exact Start menu background colour in C# under Windows 10?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, colors

I have a test project that uses a few undocumented functions to obtain the Start menu background colour:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public static class AccentColorService
    {
        static class Interop
        {
            // Thanks, Quppa! -RR

            [DllImport("uxtheme.dll", EntryPoint = "#94", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            internal static extern int GetImmersiveColorSetCount();

            [DllImport("uxtheme.dll", EntryPoint = "#95", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            internal static extern uint GetImmersiveColorFromColorSetEx(uint dwImmersiveColorSet, uint dwImmersiveColorType, bool bIgnoreHighContrast, uint dwHighContrastCacheMode);

            [DllImport("uxtheme.dll", EntryPoint = "#96", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            internal static extern uint GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName(string name);

            [DllImport("uxtheme.dll", EntryPoint = "#98", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            internal static extern uint GetImmersiveUserColorSetPreference(bool bForceCheckRegistry, bool bSkipCheckOnFail);

            [DllImport("uxtheme.dll", EntryPoint = "#100", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            internal static extern IntPtr GetImmersiveColorNamedTypeByIndex(uint dwIndex);
        }

        public static Color GetColorByTypeName(string name)
        {
            var colorSet = Interop.GetImmersiveUserColorSetPreference(false, false);
            var colorType = Interop.GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName(name);

            var rawColor = Interop.GetImmersiveColorFromColorSetEx(colorSet, colorType, false, 0);

            return FromABGR(rawColor);
        }

        public static Color FromABGR(uint abgrValue)
        {
            var colorBytes = new byte[4];
            colorBytes[0] = (byte)((0xFF000000 & abgrValue) >> 24); // A
            colorBytes[1] = (byte)((0x00FF0000 & abgrValue) >> 16); // B
            colorBytes[2] = (byte)((0x0000FF00 & abgrValue) >> 8);  // G
            colorBytes[3] = (byte)(0x000000FF & abgrValue);         // R

            return Color.FromArgb(colorBytes[0], colorBytes[3], colorBytes[2], colorBytes[1]);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Color startBackground = AccentColorService.GetColorByTypeName("ImmersiveStartBackground");
            MessageBox.Show("R: " + startBackground.R + ", G: " + startBackground.G + ", B: " + startBackground.B);
        }
    }
}
```

As I understand it, there is no official API for obtaining the various theme colours under Windows 10. I'm using, pretty much verbatim, a small snippet that I found [here](https://github.com/File-New-Project/EarTrumpet/blob/master/EarTrumpet/Services/AccentColorService.cs).

(And indeed mentioned elsewhere on Stack Overflow.)

My accent colour is the first blue that appears in the list under settings. I've turned Start menu transparency off.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDj90.png)

The colour of the Start menu with this accent is (0, 90, 158).

When I run the code above, the result displayed is:

R: 0, G: 90, B: 157

And this is not an isolated case. For other accent colours, the colour channels often have differences of +/- 2 when compared to the actual Start menu background colour.

I tried upping the saturation slightly, converting to a different colour space and back again, but nothing I've done has reliably generated the shift I'm seeing in colour channels.

Is there an additional processing step that needs to be done to the "ImmersiveStartBackground" colour to get the exact colour of the Start menu background? Alternatively, is there resource other than uxtheme.dll that I can query to obtain a more accurate precise for the Start menu background?

Comment: Are you sure the discrepancy is not because the Start menu is drawn partially transparent?

Comment: @Cody I *wasn't* sure that the Start menu was entirely opaque. I did disable Start menu transparency, but checking this was a good idea. To verify, I put a black rectangle and a white rectangle underneath the Start menu and measured the colour of the Start menu at those points. Both regions were (0, 90, 158). I think this demonstrates that it's not, for instance, 99% opaque. I mean, I'd expect some variance between a black and a white underlying layer if it were.